# iPhone Connect Facebook. Join a Page/Group Option available?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-group

I am using iPhone Connect to link my application to Facebook. Is there anyway to let user join a Page/Group on Facebook, right from the Application?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want,

http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

After adding the code to your app all you should do is to create a FBLikeButton. For example

```
FBLikeButton *likeButton = [[FBLikeButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame
andUrl:@"www.facebook.com/YOUR PAGE ID HERE"];

[view addSubview:likeButton];
```